# ¿Cómo poner un límite en una propiedad CSS con Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css

Tengo un `div` que se puede arrastrar sólo hacia arriba y hacia abajo, pero deseo que tenga un mínimo a **250px** y máximo a **650px**, ya he buscando pero aún no he podido encontrar una solución. 
Aquí podrán probar el código que llevo hasta el momento.

```js
var offset = [0];
  var divOverlay = document.querySelector(".panel__bottom-xs");
  var isDown = false;
  divOverlay.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      isDown = true;
      offset = [
          divOverlay.offsetTop - e.clientY
      ];
  }, true);
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      isDown = false;
  }, true);

  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      event.preventDefault();
      if (isDown) {
          divOverlay.style.top  = (e.clientY + offset[0]) + 'px';
          document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = divOverlay.style.top      }
  }, true);
```

```css
.panel__bottom-xs {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  left: 150px;
}
```

```html
<div class="panel__bottom-xs"></div>
<span></span>
```

De antemano muchas gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolviendo tu pregunta debes incluir un if() dentro del evento mousedown que evalue la posicion vertical del puntero en el mouse al estar fuera del rango entre 250px y un máximo a 650px no actualice la posicion top del div.

La posicion tope del div la coloque en 250px para efectos de la tabulacion

aqui te incluyo el codigo modificado.

```js
       var offset = [0];
  var divOverlay = document.querySelector(".panel__bottom-xs");
  var isDown = false;

        // evento de pulsar click
  divOverlay.addEventListener('mousedown', function(e) {
      isDown = true;
      offset = [
          divOverlay.offsetTop - e.clientY
      ];
            
  }, true);

         // evento de soltar click
  document.addEventListener('mouseup', function() {
      isDown = false;
  }, true);

        // para ambos movimentos
  document.addEventListener('mousemove', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      if (isDown) { 
                // rango entre mínimo a 250px y un máximo a 650px
                // e.clientY es el que indica la posicion vertizal del mouse
                // offset[0] tamaño del bloque
                if ( ((e.clientY + offset[0]) >= 250) && ((e.clientY - offset[0]) <= 650)) {
                    divOverlay.style.top  = (e.clientY + offset[0]) + 'px';
                }          
          document.querySelector('span').innerHTML = e.clientY;     
                }
  }, true);
```

```css
  .panel__bottom-xs {
            position: fixed;
            bottom: 0px;
            background: red;
            height: 50px;
            width: 50px;
            left: 150px;
            top:250px;
            }
```

```html
 <div class="panel__bottom-xs"></div>
    <span></span>
    <br>
    mínimo a 250px y un máximo a 650px
```